# How to properly infer generics in sequences in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have this code in java that does not compile:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Stream.of(new Parameter(fooId, fooDAO),
                  ...,
                  new Parameter(barId, barDAO))
              .forEach(parameter -> assertNotNull(parameter.dao.getById(parameter.id)))
    }

    interface DAOInterface<E extends Entity<ID>, ID> {
        E getById(ID);
    }

    class Parameter<ID, E extends Entity<ID>, DAO extends DAOInterface<E, ID>> {
        public final ID id;
        public final DAO dao;

        private Parameter(ID id, DAO dao)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.dao = dao;
        }
    }
}
```

But if I erase the type using `Stream.<Parameter>.of()` The error is reduced to a warning and it runs as expected.

However if I use `Stream<Parameter<?, ?, ?>.of()` it doesn't, because the compiler will not understand the DAO type is a DAO.

Now I need to convert this to Kotlin but given there is no such thing as type erasure I can't get it to work.

```
class MyTest {
    @Test
    fun test()
    {
        sequenceOf(Parameter(fooId, fooDAO),
                   ...,
                   Parameter(barId, barDAO))
            .forEach { parameter -> assertNotNull(parameter.dao.getById(parameter.id)) }
    }

    interface DAOInterface<E : Entity<ID>, ID> {
        fun getById(id: ID) : E
    }

    class Parameter<ID, E : Entity<ID>, DAO : DAOInterface<E, ID>>(val id: ID, val dao: DAO)
}
```

Compiler complains in `parameter.dao.getById(parameter.id)`, Required: `Nothing!`, found: `Any!`, similar to what the original Java version complains about on the first example.

Basically all entities are different and have a typed id and all DAOs have a method that finds the entity by its id.

I somehow need to instruct the compiler that the types are related but I am new to Kotlin and am lost.

I am using latest stable Kotlin 1.5

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Kotlin are you using? This works fine for me in Kotlin 1.5 (they did make some type inference improvements since 1.4). But it works in Kotlin 1.4 as well on the playground. https://pl.kotl.in/Fngz7NItT

Comment: Try `Stream.of<Parameter>()`

Comment: I am using latest stable Kotlin 1.5 with Kotlin plugin 211-1.5.10-release-891-IJ7142.45

Comment: @LouisWasserman Kotlin does not allow using erased type, that's my question in a nutshell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I somehow need to instruct the compiler that the types are related but I am new to Kotlin and am lost.

You aren't doing that in Java, though. If you use raw types, it happens to work by coincidence: `parameter.dao.getById` takes any `Object`, and `parameter.getId()` returns an `Object`. Basically, if something only works with raw types in Java it *shouldn't* work, and only does for backwards compatibility with ancient pre-generics Java versions.

The workaround (both in Kotlin and in Java) is to encapsulate

```
parameter.dao.getById(parameter.id)
```

in a helper function which can be called on `Parameter` with any type parameters and so can be called on a type with wildcards/star-projections too:

```
fun <ID, E : Entity<ID>, DAO : DAOInterface<E, ID>> Parameter<ID, E, DAO>.getSomething() = 
    dao.getById(id)
```

(obviously not an extension function in the Java case) and then

```
sequenceOf<Parameter<*, *, *>>(
    Parameter(fooId, fooDAO),
    Parameter(barId, barDAO)
)
.forEach { parameter -> println(parameter.getSomething()) }
```

You can probably write just `sequenceOf(...)`, but this is [to show that it does work with star-projection](https://pl.kotl.in/TqRdFQlJP).

Comment: "only does for backwards compatibility with ancient pre-generics Java versions" - Which Kotlin is also supposed to, or not?

Comment: @PedroBorges No, because Kotlin was created long after these versions became obsolete.

Comment: @PedroBorges: More detail: the main reason Java has raw types is to allow pre-generics code to compile in versions which have generics and to be called from new code when it has `List`, `Collection`, etc. in signatures, so it didn't have to be rewritten immediately. But of course there's no Kotlin pre-generics code and every at all maintained Java library had been updated to have generics by the time Kotlin appeared.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am marking your answer as correct, but bottom line is there is something I can do in Java that I can't in Kotlin.

Comment: Yes, but the thing you can do in Java is unsafe. E.g. if you replace with `parameter.dao.getById("")` it will work as well even for parameters whose `ID` is not `String`. Well, it will compile and throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime without any apparent casts.

Comment: Yes, it is unsafe but possible, yet impossible in Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the Java code.

You tried to let the compiler infer the type parameter of `Stream.of`.
It failed most likely because the types of its arguments are not consistent.
In the question, you didn't describe the type of variable `fooId`, `fooDAO`, `barId`, `barDAO` etc.
It's possible their types vary.

For instance, they have types of `FooId`, `FooDao`, `BarId`, `BarDao`.
Thus the parameters of `Stream.of` will be `Parameter<FooId, FooEntity, FooDao>` and `Parameter<BarId, BarEntity, BarDao>`. (Note that the types `FooEntity` and `BarEntity` are inferred from `FooDao` and `BarDao`)

Given this, the compiler can't find a correct type that to be compatible with all arguments.

Once you used `Stream.<Parameter>of`, you forced the compiler to ignore the type parameters and you got a warning about it.
To eliminate the warning, you need to find fallback types for `ID`, `E`, and `DAO`. You could use the wildcard `Paramter<?, ?, ?>`, if you can't find concrete types for all the parameters.

Then, the Kotlin code.

It may have the same reason: failed on type inference.
Kotlin compiler tries to use common ancestor as the type parameter, it may become type `Nothing` in your case.

So choose types carefully.

Comment: You just described the question :) My point is that inside the for loop whatever Parameter type there is I need the compiler to understand that that Parameter's DAO has a method that takes that parameter's ID. That doesn't work with wildcards but it works with erasure. Can I erase in Kotlin as I do in Java?

Comment: I just updated the question, I can't use Parameter<?, ?, ?> it won't work, only works with erased type - the compiler is less strict with erased types and allows the code to compile and it works.